# $40^8 \cdot 80^4 = 2^x \cdot 5^y$ -Finding the $x+y$

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

$$40^8 \cdot 80^4 = 2^x \cdot 5^y$$

- Find the $x+y$

So, this question seems really too easy. However, the thing is to know where to start. Let me explain what I thought. I see that $2$ and $5$ are both divisor of $40$ and $80$. Also, personally I'd like to ask an anohter question as well.

- Is there any strategy to solve these equalities which involve exponential terms?

Regards!

Comment: Yes, factor $40$ and $80$ and use laws of exponents.

Comment: You're right, $2,5$ are both divisors of $40,80$. Can you factorize $40$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ 2^x \cdot 5^y=40^8 \cdot 80^4 =(2^35)^8(2^45)^4=2^{40}5^{12}$

$x=40$ and $y=12$.

Answer (score 1):

$(2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 5)^8 \cdot (2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 5)^4 = 2^{40} \cdot 5^{12}$

Comment: Thank you, I've searched around but don't find how to format in math text.

Answer (score 0):

$$40^8 \cdot 80^4 = 2^x \cdot 5^y\\ { \left( { 2 }^{ 3 }\cdot 5 \right)  }^{ 8 }\cdot { \left( { 2 }^{ 4 }\cdot 5 \right)  }^{ 4 }={ 2 }^{ x }\cdot { 5 }^{ y }\\ { 2 }^{ 24+16 }\cdot { 5 }^{ 8+4 }={ 2 }^{ x }\cdot { 5 }^{ y }\\ x=40,y=12 $$